# create a webpage popup using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, html

How to create a open a webpage as a popup using c# and need to run a function when the popup window is closed. my intention is to create a  web login/logout and run  a function after successful completion of the event

Answer (score 1):

Well you've not given much away, but if I'm guessing that your architecture is ASP.NET, then you should have events on the server in your page's codebehind that can process that event.  If you expand a bit on your requirements we can help you out a bit more.

Just for completeness, you should know that you can't just run C# code in a browser with html/javascript.  You could run a Silverlight application but I don't think that's what you're after.

To summarise, make a web request and respond to it on the server.  Popups are just webpages, so the architecture there is the same.  When the request comes back, you can then run JS to close the popup and make the main browser window do something.

Personally I'd just have the main browser do the login, popups are cumbersome for users in web apps.

Comment: Thanks Niel, 
currently im having a c# application, in which i need to implement a login section and i have an api for this login purpose.. so what i need is to create a popup pointing to that url to perform the login/logout and need to call a function after closing this window. I think you got me now .....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, I would strongly suggest using ThickBox http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ We use it in every single projects we do and it work very weel and it's easy to modify to have it do what you want.

You can use it to load another aspx page where your login code would reside and then pay particual attention to

function tb_remove() {

Which is called on close. This is where we added our code to return data to the page.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't. C# runs on the server and opening a popup window is a client side action. You will need to have JavaScript in your rendered markup to open the popup window when appropriate, or an anchor tag with target="_blank".

However, I agree with the other answers that popup windows are more of a pain than they are worth, they annoy users and lead to window management issues that are not always easy to solve especially when popup blockers are involved. A DOM based modal dialog is almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Neil... Sorry to say this but you are exactly the type of person Jeff Atwood was talking about when he wrote this article...

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001296.html

I would suggest you take the time to learn the difference between client and server functionality, languages and technology.

I would also suggest you listen to Neil, your usability skills also need serious work.

LOL - and if you think I'm being cruel, think how cruel you're being to your users... login in a pop up window... bah